# Web Crawling :How to obtain URLs which use database information?

Tags: python, post, web, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is my problem statement :

I'm trying to retrieve all the well specific information for a state from http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/  . After doing a bit of R&D , i figured out that individual well information is stored in path structured as :

http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100280000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml

where each KeyValue is unique for every well.I was trying to derive a generic pattern in the KeyValue - for above URL eg in 3143100280000 , 03 represents state(arkansas),143 represents County , but the remaining no - 100280000 is not necessarily following a serial pattern and thus makes life difficult.

Is there a way through which all the KeyValues for 43K+ wells be obtained here (which i'm presuming is coming from a database) ?Tried looking for all sources js files being loaded from http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/  but none points towards all KeyValues/Well API source directory

Using Python Scrapy i've written the following spider which crawls few specific Well XML URLs.In need to make this generic so as to obtain all 43k+ well information but not being able to attain a way to figure out all the KeyValues here

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import codecs

class AogcSpider(Spider):
name = "aogc"
allowed_domains = ["http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100280000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml",
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100290000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml",
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100300000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml",
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100310000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml",
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100320000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml",
    "http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us/AOGConline/ED.aspx?KeyName=API_WELLNO&KeyValue=03143100330000&KeyType=STRING&DetailXML=WellDetails.xml"
]

def parse(self,response):
    hxs =  Selector(response)
    trnodes = hxs.xpath("//td[@class='ColumnValue']")
    filename = codecs.open("aogc_wells","a","utf-8-sig")
    filename.write("\n")
    for nodes in trnodes:
        ftext = nodes.xpath("text()").extract()
        for txt in ftext:
            filename.write(txt)
            filename.write("|")
```

Comment: I think you need to use their search function to query their database. However, the search function only allows for 50 results, with NO next button. So you are going to need to find a parameter that can be varied finely, so to only get no more than 50 results per query. It's going to be a lot of queries.